# An approximately constant loss but improving accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have defined a custom loss funnction, "Categorical Focal Loss":

```
class CategoricalFocalLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.25, gamma=2, l1=0.01, l2=0.01, **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalFocalLoss, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #Code Here
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        FL = - self.alpha * y_true * tf.math.pow(1 - y_pred, self.gamma) * tf.math.log(y_pred)
        l1 = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.abs(y_pred))
        l2 = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_pred))
        total_loss = FL + self.l1 * l1 + self.l2 * l2
        return total_loss
```

When I train my model, my loss remains ratherly constant, but accuracy increases:
[image: training logs]

Is this something that I must be anxious about?

Comment: Do you use one-hot encoded labels/predictions?

Comment: Yes, I do. @mhenning

Answer (score 1):

So I looked at your loss with a few example values (rounded values here):

```
y_true = [[1., 0.], [1., 0.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.]]
y_pred = [[9.99e-01, 1.23e-04], [9.93e-01, 6.69e-03], [7.31e-01, 2.68e-01], [2.86e-20, 1.00e+00], [2.11e-19, 1.00e+00], [1.38e-11, 1.00e+00]]
y_pred_random = [[0.57, 0.42], [0.49, 0.50], [0.48 0.51], [0.59, 0.40], [0.57, 0.4284914], [0.68, 0.31]]
y_pred_middle = [[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]]
```

There are 6 samples, with `y_pred`, `y_pred_random` and `y_pred_middle` normalized by softmax.
`y_pred` is a really good prediction of `y_true`, `y_pred_random` is sampled from a random uniform distribution and `y_pred_middle` is a classifier that can't decide for a class.
I modified your code so that the loss function prints out the l1 and l2 part of `total_loss` separately (`print(self.l1*l1, self.l2*l2)`). When we then calculate the loss with your standard parameters we get the following:

```
loss_fn = CategoricalFocalLoss()
loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)  # very good prediction
-> l1 = 0.06, l2 = 0.0559, total_loss = 0.1164
loss_fn(y_true, y_pred_random)  # random values
-> l1 = 0.06, l2 = 0.0311, total_loss = 0.1246
loss_fn(y_true, _y_pred_middle)  # middle ground predictions
-> l1 = 0.06, l2 = 0.03, total_loss = 0.1116
```

So, what can we see here? First, the loss can't get smaller than `0.06` (with 6 samples) due to the l1 term, which will always add the number of predictions * 0.01 to the loss. Second, the stronger the predicion (for better or worse), the larger gets the l2 term (in the almost perfect prediction `y_pred` l1+l2 makes up 99.5% of `total_loss`).
You can also see that l1 and l2 make up large parts of the loss in all examples, and the almost perfect example has a worse loss than the prediction with all `0.5`. What was your reasoning behind the l1 and l2 terms? I would either modify them, remove them, or shrink the terms even more.